# How views connected using url

Tags: swift, url

Is there any way I can link my app to a certain url that can direct it to a certain views with specified informaion

> for example : twitter https://twitter.com/naifco/status/0101010101010101?s=21 // just a fake url

will direct you to a certain tweet in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will solve your problem using URL Scheme, here is the Apple documentation link for that:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

Hope I helped you!

Comment: In general, it is good practice to provide at least a summary of the solution in the post. While the link is very much welcomed, posts should provide enough information so that readers can get an idea of how the answer solves the problem without having to click on the link